# Control Pivot Table filter via Dropdown Box

Tags: excel, vba

I use below **VBA** code to control Manufacturer field of the "`Dropdown`" pivot table via drop down box. Based on the selection from drop down box pivot table manufacturer field should change. Code used to work perfectly but its giving me error since i changed the pivot table and highlights below row in yellow.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Dropdown").PivotFields("Manufacturer").ClearAllFilters
```

Comment: Without seeing the VBA code, the error message, nor how you changed the pivot table, the answer is no, we can't advise.

Comment: Sorry here is the code i am using.

Sub Dropdown()

'

'Dropdown Macro
'

'
Sheets("POS Tracker").Select
Sheets("POS Tracker").Visible = True
Sheets("Source").Visible = True
Sheets("Source").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Manufacturer").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Manufacturer").CurrentPage = "(All)"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Manufacturer").CurrentPage = Range("C114").Text
Sheets("Source").Visible = False


End Sub

Comment: You need to edit your question to add the code, not include it as a comment. (And please don't forget to [format your code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)).

Comment: And again, without an error message or knowledge of how you've changed your pivot table, we still can't help.